# Mongo query "$avg" returning nan without error message

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo query where I try to calculate the average over a large database subseection I tried both to use $bucket and manually iterate with $match.

With a small subsection of the database it works, but if I do it with the full datebase I get only nan as return.

What could be the cause for this?

```
query = self.mongodb_archive.price_scrape_historical.aggregate([

    {
        "$match": {"seconds_until_start": {"$gt": from_sec, "$lt": to_sec}}
    },

    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "null",
            "avg_ltp": {"$avg": "$LTP"}
        }
    }

],
    allowDiskUse=True)
return list(query)
```

Comment: you might have NaN LTP in your document, that's why it returns NaN

Comment: According to the documentation non numeric values are ignored.

Comment: typeof NaN is number, it might ignore other types such as string, object, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried `$avg` with `NaN` as numeric value, here is the result on Mongo3.4

```
> db.tt.insert({amount: NaN})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.tt.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a8fcfb5ce385223408b4178"), "amount" : NaN }

> db.tt.aggregate([{$group : {_id : null, avg : {$avg : "$amount"}}}])
{ "_id" : null, "avg" : NaN }
```

so it's clear you have a `NaN` in your numeric field

and **typeof NaN is number**, so it is not ignored

Comment: Yes I do, is there a way to ignore them?

Comment: Yes, use `$match` to filter or don't set `NaN` in document

Comment: The documentation clearly says that non numeric values are ignored. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/

Comment: check the typeof NaN, its number